# How to remove the old github author and add a new one?

Tags: git, github

I have created a second GitHub account on my computer, and I want to use it for now. I have changed the `git config` username and email both globally:

```
git config --global user.name "xyz"
git config --global user.email "xyz@mail.com"
```

But when I make a commit, the commit shown is from the author of the first GitHub account. Is there something else that I have to change?

Comment: Are you using SSH?

Comment: From within the repository you're working on, do `git config get user.name` and `git config get user.email` show what you expect? Where are you viewing the author information...locally, using e.g. `git log`, or via your browser at github.com?

Comment: Do know that "github account" and "user.name"/"user.email" are two distinct things. In order to get git to push to or fetch from a different account you need to change the repository remote url and possibly the authentication used with github. The user.name/email is used when committing to add author name to the commit, and does not directly translate to something related to a github account.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the git credentials on your computer in the *credential manager* and login with the new created user again.

To remove the git credentials follow this steps:

- Open <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> -> <kbd>User Account</kbd> -> <kbd>Credential Manager</kbd> or search directly for "Credential Manager"
- Remove the "old" git account credentials by removing the entry

After removing the git credentials, when you execute the first command to the remote server (as example `git pull`) you will be asked to login to the remote server, now with the "new" acount.

The command `git config --global user.name` or `git config --global user.email` change only username and email in the git commit history
as the user @Lasse V. Karlsen mentioned in the comments.